# f $G$ is generated by 2 elements, and has a free subgroup $L$ of rank $n+1$, where $|G:L|=n$, then $G$ is free of rank $2$.

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, infinite-groups

A question from a past exam paper I am trying to solve:

If $G$ is generated by 2 elements, and has a free subgroup $L$ of rank $n+1$, where $|G:L|=n$, then $G$ is free of rank $2$.

I am not sure how to go about this. I understand how to prove the sort of converse, that if $G$ were free of rank $2$ and $L$ a subgroup of index $n$ then $L$ free of rank $1 + n(2-1) = n + 1$ (Neilsen-Schreier) but I can't seem to get started with this.

Any hints or help would be appreciated.

Comment: sorry that should be 2!

Comment: Carry out the Reidemeister-Schreier algorithm on the subgroup $L$ of $G$. This will give a presentation of $L$ on the $n+1$ Schreier generators. If there were any nontrivial  relators of $G$, then they would result in nontrivial relators of $L$, so $L$ would not be free of rank $n+1$.